# Simulating Heavy Usage in Rails / Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, web-applications, heroku

Is there a tool that can help me simulate high levels of usage of my rails app? I'm looking to test how responsive it will stay as usage grows. I'm deploying on Heroku and I'd like to know at what point to add additional capacity.

Something that could also give me performance stats would be especially useful.

Comment: Dont know if that'll go over well with heroku ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) (free) to test your dev and production site. You also can use something like [BLITZ.IO](http://blitz.io/) but it'll cost money (free service has a duration/user limit).

Answer (score 3):

The Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool is what you are looking for: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Then run your test with

```
ab -c 20 -n 5000 http://www.yourdomain.com/
```

to see the performance of you application with 20 consecutive requests and 5,000 requests in total.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495796/how-much-performance-do-you-get-out-a-heroku-dynos-workers) and [this](http://benscheirman.com/2010/08/load-testing-our-heroku-app) on heroku performance.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is [Loader.io](http://loader.io) by SendGrid. It let's you test up to 50,000 connections for free.

I tried a number of tools and found this one to be excellent. A lot easier to use than JMeter I found.