# How much can the free version of Heroku handle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

For a mostly static website without a lot of stuff going on in the back end, how many page views can the free version of heroku handle (ruby on rails). Can it handle 100 a month, 1,000, 10,000, etc. When shoudl I consider upgrading it and are there better services? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only real answer to this question is "It depends". It depends on how many database calls you are making, whether or not those database calls are optimized, whether you have any form of caching in place, etc.

However, I am currently in a similar situation as you and just launched an early stage startup on Heroku. I highly recommend installing [New Relic](https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic) (don't worry, there's a free tier) to keep an eye on site usage/statistics.

Another (free!) addon I installed was [Papertrail](https://addons.heroku.com/papertrail), which allows me to keep a close eye on the Heroku logs, and trigger alerts if there are too many errors (which could mean it's time to scale-up).

On the other side, you can test your Heroku server by sending load to it using the Apache Bend tool. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495796/how-much-performance-do-you-get-out-a-heroku-dynos-workers#answer-4502958) for a good explanation.

Lastly, I would take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495796/how-much-performance-do-you-get-out-a-heroku-dynos-workers), which provides many good references on Heroku performance.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is free for up to 5 apps. Each app has access to 750 dyno-hours per month. That should be more then enough for a mostly static site.

Answer (score 0):

I get about 4k-5k visitors per month on a Ruby app, but with a lot of caching.